# curl CURLE_WRITE_ERROR error

Tags: c++, curl

I am using curl_multi_info_read in cpp.

If the other device doesnt response to the request, i expect to get curl error code CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT but instead I get the error code CURLE_WRITE_ERROR (retrieved from msg->data.result).

Why do I get the error CURLE_WRITE_ERROR?

Answer (score 0):

CURLE_WRITE_ERROR (23)

An error occurred when writing received data to a local file, or an error was returned to libcurl from a write callback.

Please post your code, so that we can help.